# Applying CSS on JavaFx TreeTableView fails

Tags: css, java-8, javafx-8, treetableview

I'm trying to apply some CSS on JavaFx8 TreeTableView and when I run the application I get

```
Feb 04, 2015 9:13:24 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "font-size: 10px;" not found.
```

and here is the code I'm using:

```
private TreeItem<ZajelUser> root;
root = ...
TreeTableView<ZajelUser> treeTableView;
treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(root);
treeTableView.getStylesheets().add("font-size: 10px;");
treeTableView.applyCss();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two mistakes here:

1. If you want to apply CSS styles directly, use [`Node.setStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setStyle-java.lang.String-). Otherwise create a CSS file, write the rules there and attach the stylesheet with `treeTableView.getStylesheets().add("myStyles.css;");`
2. You should change `font-size: 10px;` to `-fx-font-size: 10px;`.

See the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Comment: If this answers your question, please "accept" this answer ;-)